# How can I set QoS in moquette broker?

Tags: java, mqtt, qos, moquette

I am using moquette as my MQTT broker in my project.

I want to set QoS as 0, 1 or 2 and want to see the behavior.

Is there any possibility that I can set it using moquette.conf ?

Following is the moquette.conf file's content :

```
Moquette Java Broker configuration file for testing
port 1884
websocket_port 8080
host 0.0.0.0
persistence false

allow_anonymous true

allow_zero_byte_client_id false
```

How can I set QoS ?

Comment: QoS is a property of a message when it's published by a client (or when the client makes a subscription). There is nothing to set in the broker (apart from enabling persistence, which is required for QoS 1/2 to work properly)

Comment: I got your point. The concept was quite unclear at that time. Thanks for the clarification.